# Is there an easy way to remove nodes while keeping descendants?

Tags: python, networkx

I've got a graph with some nodes I'd like to remove based on criteria. Is there an easy way to remove the node, but keep the descendants in tact?

Super simple, but say I've got this graph:
1->2->3->4->5->6

If 2 and 4 meet criteria for removal, how can I be left with something like the following?
1->3->5->6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`contracted_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.minors.contracted_nodes.html):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
nx.add_path(G, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])


drop = [2, 4]
for node in drop:
    try:
        nx.contracted_nodes(G, next(G.predecessors(node)), node,
                            self_loops=False, copy=False)
    except StopIteration:
        G.remove_node(node)
```

Or:

```
for node in drop:
    for p in G.predecessors(node):
        nx.contracted_nodes(G, p, node,
                            self_loops=False, copy=False)
    if node in G:
        G.remove_node(node)
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Output with `drop = [1, 2, 3, 6]`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Before removing a node, collect the targets of all incoming and outgoing edges. After you remove the node, recreate new edges using this data.

```py
def pop_node(g, node):
    outgoing = {v for u, v in g.edges if u == node}
    incoming = {u for u, v in g.edges if v == node}
    g.remove_node(node)
    g.add_edges_from([(u, v) for u in incoming for v in outgoing])
```

Example usage:

```
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edges_from([(i, i+1) for i in range(1, 6)])

nx.draw(g, with_labels=True)
plt.show()

pop_node(g, 2)
pop_node(g, 4)

nx.draw(g, with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

Before removals:

[image: before removals]

After removals:

[image: after removals]